# ArrayAdapter.addAll(T... items) not flagged by eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My Min SDK is 9 and Target is 19. Even if I change my Target to android:targetSdkVersion="9", eclipse does not flag adapter.addAll(Records); I assumed that the support library appcompat_v7 was supporting this code. Code works fine on API 19 but when I test on API 10, the app crashed for:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.timeclock.MainActivity$MyAdapter.addAll

I understand the "workaround".
Eclipse complains fairly regularly when I try to do something that is not supported by my API or the support library.

Is my eclipse not set up correctly or is this the reason that I should always test and not assume?

Comment: Can you Show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

The `addAll()` method requires API 11. [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

You can extend the `ArrayAdapter` class and add the code yourself as it's not very hard: [ArrayAdapter.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java)